# Skipping columns in R read.table()

Tags: r

I wanna skip the first three columns. Couldn't quite understand the posts about colClasses because I'm new to R.

```
YDL025C YDL025C 1   -0.1725 -0.5375 -0.4970 -0.3818 -0.5270 -0.4260 -0.6929 -0.4020 -0.3263 -0.3373 -0.3532 -0.2771 -0.2732 -0.3307 -0.4660 -0.4314 -0.3135
YKL032C YKL032C 1   -0.2364 0.0794  0.1678  0.2389  0.3847  0.2625  0.1889  0.2681  0.0363  -0.1992 -0.0521 -0.0307 0.0584  0.2817  0.2239  -0.0253 0.0751
```

Comment: In `fread` (`data.table`) there is `select` option to select the columns

Comment: But I need to use read.table so please explain to me how to use the colClasses here, thx

Comment: why not skipping them after...

Comment: @akrun I can't believe I might be able to inform the master!  You can use colClass to specify the columns with NULL that you don't want to include. See below. However, memory wise, I don't know if it reads it in and then removes, or just skips over.  I assume the latter.

Comment: @akaDrHouse  yes, i forgot about it.

Answer (score 6):

If you have to use read.table and you want to filter on the way in, you can use col.classes as follows.  You have 20 columns. Say the first 2 are character, rest are numeric and you want to drop 4,5,6.  You construct a vector of length 20 detailing that information.  The NULL will not pull in those columns.

```
x<- read.table(file="datat.txt", 
               colClasses = c(rep("character", 2),
                              rep("numeric", 1),
                              rep("NULL", 3),
                              rep("numeric", 14)),
               header = FALSE)
x

       V1      V2 V3      V7      V8      V9     V10     V11     V12     V13     V14     V15     V16     V17     V18     V19     V20
1 YDL025C YDL025C  1 -0.3818 -0.5270 -0.4260 -0.6929 -0.4020 -0.3263 -0.3373 -0.3532 -0.2771 -0.2732 -0.3307 -0.4660 -0.4314 -0.3135
2 YKL032C YKL032C  1  0.2389  0.3847  0.2625  0.1889  0.2681  0.0363 -0.1992 -0.0521 -0.0307  0.0584  0.2817  0.2239 -0.0253  0.0751
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Wasn't working initially because I didn't have quotes around NULL.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, easier to remove the columns after reading in. For example:

```
mydf <- read.table("mydf.txt")
```

Then,

```
mydf[, 4:ncol(mydf)]
```

will remove the first 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

The `read.table` function returns a data frame. So, you can remove the columns before assigning the results of `read.table` function to your variable. For example, the following code will skip first 5 columns:

```
df <- read.table("df.txt")[,c(-1:-5)]
```