# How to import txt file with uneven column numbers

Tags: r, import, readline, txt, read.table

i would like to read and tidy a large txt file in r. The file looks like this

"X1"  "ID_t.x"  "Pro"  "Her"  "We"  .....(22 column)
"1"  4  "string"  101  "2ndstring"  NA  ....(23 column)
"2"  2  "xstring"  101  "ystring"  12  ....(23 column)
"3"  7  "ystring"  101  "zstring"  NA  ....(23 column)
"4"  5  "astring"  101  "bstring"  NA  ....(23 column)

and soon
the problem is that first row is a header and 2nd row has a extra column at the beginning with row number for element making it one more column than header. The separator is a double space.It doesn't work with read.table(). I would be grateful if someone can help

I tried it line break but it wont work.

it should look like this:

```
"X1"  "ID_t.x"   "Pro"  "Her"       "We"  .....(22 column)
```

"1"  4    "string"   101   "2ndstring"  NA  ....(23 column)
"2"  2    "xstring"  101   "ystring"    12  ....(23 column)
"3"  7    "ystring"  101   "zstring"    NA  ....(23 column)
"4"  5    "astring"  101   "bstring"    NA  ....(23 column)

Comment: Also see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260209/skipping-columns-in-r-read-table

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the help file of the read.table command, it could work with:

```
?read.table
read.table(x, sep = " ", header = T, fill = T)
```

If it doesn't work, try to manually write the headers for each column using `col.names = c()` in your read.table command:

```
read.table(x, sep = " ", header = T, col.names = c("colname1", "colname2", etc.), fill = T)
```